# Custom URL rewrite in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, url-rewriting, blogs

I am trying to achieve a custom URL structure with Wordpress. Basically, my site functions as my blog and my portfolio. I want to have an "Articles" section and a "Portfolio" section. I want the articles to display on the Articles page, and the portfolio on the Portfolio page. Should be easy, except on top of that I want custom URLs...

I want the URLs setup like this:

Articles page:
http://mydomain.com/discusses

Specific article:
http://mydomain.com/discussed/%postname%

Portfolio page:
http://mydomain.com/does

Specific design:
http://mydomain.com/designed/%postname%

I can figure out how to do only one rewrite of this type, but WP doesn't have built in functionality to do both. I'm just wondering where I should start or what I should do...

The problem also becomes, I want to retain category functionality in both areas, so maybe it needs to be achieved with Custom Fields? and add a new rewrite rule based on the custom field of a post? I have idea where to start...

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Can you give examples of the non-rewritten urls, the not clean ones that wordpress uses for those articles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually isn't that hard to do. I'll go down, page by page, what you would need to do to achieve this.

**Articles Page**

Create a new template in your theme folder (/wp-content/themes/your-theme/) called discusses.php and just add the following content:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Discusses Template
*/
?>
```

You don't need any more content. Go into the Pages section of WordPress Admin and create a new page called Articles page and set the URL to be /discusses/. Set the template of this page to be Discusses Template. Now, go into the Settings → Reading section in Admin and set the Posts page to Articles page. Now all your blog posts will appear under the URL /discusses/

**Specific Article**

The easiest way to have all your articles appearing as /discussed/title is to rename the default category (in Posts → Categories) to discussed. Then set your permalinks to be:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

This will render the links you need for each post.

**Portfolio Page & Specific Design Page**

Assuming this will be some kind of custom design, the easiest thing to do would be to create a custom template and Page in the pages section, as you did for the articles page, and throw your custom HTML and CSS into that. I would then set each specific design page to be a child page of that in the pages section. You can use the [WPdb classs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class) to make custom queries to populate the Portfolio page.

Comment: Woah thank you for such an in depth response! The only problem is that I wanted to retain the category function, and also have the portfolio pieces be posts as well.

But I think I have found the solution while continuing to search after posting this topics. Something called "custom taxonomies". I can create a category-like/tag-like container that I can use in the exact same way. I am going to have it called "type" and then have values for posts be either "article" or "portfolio". And then in each page, I can hopefully run a loop that gets all posts with those specific value for "type"

Comment: Ran out of space above, but I wanted to say thanks again for such a detailed comment. Much appreciated!